# Image position next to table

Tags: tables, graphics

I'm trying to add an image, inside a table to the far right of a table, centered horizontally.

This is my code and the result:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{150,150,150}
    \noindent\colorbox{shadecolor}
    {\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textsc{\Huge \scshape Tim - Computer Guy}}}

    \begin{tabular}{l r}
        \textbf{Phone:} & +1 123456\\
        \textbf{Email:} & \href{mailto:x@x.com}{\underline{abc@12345.com}}  \\
        \textbf{LinkedIn:} & \href{https://linkedin.com/in/...}{\underline{linkedin.com/in/.../}} \\
        \textbf{Nationality: } & American \\
        \textbf{Current Location: } & Somewhere\\ 
        \textbf{Drivers License: } & Florida \\
        \textbf{Age: } & 42 \\ 
    \end{tabular}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5, valign=center]{Photo.JPG}
    
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So it's almost there, but not quite. This is the position I really want the image:
[image]

I've been trying to figure this out for a bit, but haven't been able to figure out how to implement any of the solutions from search results.

I might be going about this the wrong way entirely. Can anyone suggest the best/correct way to do this?

My goal is to modify a popular resume template to suit a different industry. This is the example in overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/4845267945mdmycwgpzjvk
and this is the original that I am hacking away at:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/jakes-resume/syzfjbzwjncs

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please make your code compilable, so we don't have to guess your document class, which packages you're loadin, &c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution with the `floatrow` package:

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{geometry}
        \usepackage{xcolor}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{floatrow}
        \usepackage{hyperref}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{table}
            \definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{150,150,150}
            \noindent\colorbox{shadecolor}
            {\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textsc{\Huge \scshape Tim - Computer Guy}}}

        \begin{floatrow}\CenterFloatBoxes
            \ttabbox{}{\begin{tabular}{l r}
                \textbf{Phone:} & +1 123456\\
                \textbf{Email:} & \href{mailto:x@x.com}{\underline{abc@12345.com}} \\
                \textbf{LinkedIn:} & \href{https://linkedin.com/in/...}{\underline{linkedin.com/in/.../}} \\
                \textbf{Nationality: } & American \\
                \textbf{Current Location: } & Somewhere\\
                \textbf{Drivers License: } & Florida \\
                \textbf{Age: } & 42 \\
            \end{tabular}}
            \ffigbox{\hfill\includegraphics{manray}}{}
        \end{floatrow}
        \end{table}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great, thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `adjustbox` with optional `export`, you probably just need to change `valign=center` to `valign=c`.

As to the horizontal alignment, adding `\hfill` between the table and the image creates necessary space to push the image far right.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

        
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{150,150,150}
    \centering
    \colorbox{shadecolor}%
    {\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textsc{\Huge \scshape Tim - Computer Guy}}}

    \nointerlineskip% removes small white space above the image
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l r@{}}
        \textbf{Phone:} & +1 123456\\
        \textbf{Email:} & \href{mailto:x@x.com}{\underline{abc@12345.com}}  \\
        \textbf{LinkedIn:} & \href{https://linkedin.com/in/...}{\underline{linkedin.com/in/.../}} \\
        \textbf{Nationality: } & American \\
        \textbf{Current Location: } & Somewhere\\ 
        \textbf{Drivers License: } & Florida \\
        \textbf{Age: } & 42 \\ 
    \end{tabular}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5, valign=c]{example-image}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```